# MySQL gem is not installing on M1 mac

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apple-m1

I am facing issue while installing MySQL gem on M1 mac. Bundle install fas failing to build mysql gem

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.3), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

Found a solution which suggested to install mysql2 gem using following command

```
$ arch -x86_64 gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3 -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

This actually solved bundle install issue, but when i tried `rails c` got this error.

```
$ rails c
   
/Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2.rb:36:in `<main>'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/bundler-2.3.8/lib/bundler.rb:176:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/maneeshb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the issue

```
brew install openssl zstd mysql

LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix zstd)/lib/:$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/ gem install mysql2
```